# Parse free account Class name limit?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm new to `Parse` so please forgive me.  I setup a free `Parse` account for my `iOS` project I'm working on using `Xcode7` and `Swift 2`.  Is there a limit to the number of `Class` `Names` you can create, in your free `Parse` account for a particular app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only limit its the storage, request, cloud jobs and data transfer as you can see here http://parse.com/pricing

Comment: Ok, I appreciate it.  I did see this, but wasn't if there was a limit aside from the storage.  Thank you.